# Cyanogen rooted Defy+ not recognized by ADT

Tags: android, adt, cyanogenmod

I'm developing an application using the Android Development Tools and would like to use my Cyanogen rooted Motorola Defy+ phone as a test device. When I connect it via USB, the Android Device Chooser shows it's serial number as "?????????", AVD name as "unknown" and does not allow a connection. Is there a work around for this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that worked for me is described here: 
http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html#setting-up

I needed to create a rules file here "/etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules"

that has the USB Vendor ID (22b8) for my Motorola, (look that up here, http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html#VendorIds). The contents of 51-android.rules is,
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="22b8", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev". 
Then execute this, "chmod a+r /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules" as root and restart.

Answer (score 0):

Try going [here](https://motorola-global-portal.custhelp.com/app/answers/prod_detail/a_id/79551/p/30,6720,7695) and downloading the latest USB drivers. That should fix it to allow debugging on your phone. This worked for me (albeit with a GS3 and Samsung drivers) when I started.

Comment: I'm running Linux on my laptop. I have no trouble connecting w/the unit. This appears to be an ADT issue.

Comment: ...also ADT connects fine w/my other Android devices running stock ROMs.

Answer (score 0):

Did you unlock the developer options in your Settings? You can unlock them by clicking in the "About your phone" section 5 times on the "Build Date". After I installed I had to do this again. Eventhough I had unlocked them previously. This worked for me.

Comment: Yes, developer settings are enabled on the Cyanogen device.